# Improving deployment process of agent software

Tags: ansible, deployment, practices

I'm a developer on an agent software team, researching ways to streamline the mass deployment of our agent on clients' machines. Currently the process involves running a script to determine the exact package needed, downloading a bsx from our company's FTP and running it, followed by running an executable with flags for registration.

I've looked into Ansible as a possible improvement, however I'm unclear on the value it provides in such a case. What's more, I'm not sure I'm the right person to be authoring the clients' playbooks for such a thing. At this point it would appear to me that developing our own script to further automate the process would be a better solution, and let the customer DevOps team deploy it in whichever way they see fit.

Before I present these findings to my managers, I would appreciate any opinions on the matter the community could provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ansible-pull](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_intro.html#ansible-pull) would work well for this, though it makes the assumption that your clients are using ansible. That's not an assumption I would be comfortable making in your shoes.

> At this point it would appear to me that developing our own script to further automate the process would be a better solution

I agree with that. Since you already have a script to figure out what needs to be downloaded, I'd extend that script to download the needed file(s) and trigger the installation/registration.